# Is the fighter character allotment of CPs wrong?

Tags: adnd-2e

I have the *Player's Options: Skills & Powers* book with soft cover, it should be with a lot of error corrected, at least the corrections made in the [FAQ/Errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/DnDPlayersOptionSkillsPowersErrata.asp) of first printing were made (2nd too). But in page 47, Fighter description, grey box, is said:

> Fighters have 15 character points to spend on abilities.

and

> A standard fighter spends his character points to acquire the
>   abilities of weapon specialization and gaining followers.

However, the first level of the Followers ability costs 5 CPs and Weapon specialization, 5 CPs too. **Multiple** specialization costs 10 CPs.

Is it a error? The standard rule for specialization here is the same of Fighter's Handbook or Player's Handbook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number is correct. It’s not even low — it’s actually more than a PHB fighter would count as having.

The equivalent of the standard PHB fighter class can be built by spending only 10 Character Points: 5 CP on Weapon Specialization and 5 CP on Followers (the version that only kicks in at level 9). That leaves a S&P fighter with 5 CP to spend on abilities the PHB version doesn’t get (such as getting Multiple Specialization instead, or the ability to attract Followers before level 9, or any of the ability choices unique to S&P fighters).

(Mind that the CP cost for Weapon Specialization or Multiple Specialization is to get the *ability* to specialize at all. These CP aren’t for spending on specific specializations. You get more CP later for buying proficiencies, including specializations.)

You don’t even need to spend the 5 or 10 CP for Followers yet, because that can be bought later with CP earned from levelling up. Leaving the Followers ability for buying later would give 10 CP extra over the PHB-equivalent fighter.

Note too that the fighter’s race will grant CP (some of which can be saved for spending on other parts of character creation), and more CP are granted in the proficiencies steps, so this 15 CP from class is not the only starting CP this fighter will get.

Comment: The question was made mainly because standard ranger and paladin spends all CPs and also because there was a discussion (in my group at least) if PHB allowed multiple specialization or it is allowed only in FHB.

Comment: @Lucas It’s a good idea to explain the question *in* the question. (The part about Fighter’s HB specialization vs. PHB specialization might be better in a separate question, though.) That said, I don’t think that changes the answer, unless I’m misunderstanding what you mean.